# Emulate Sound Card ALSA snd-dummy (Docker - Kernel Rebuild - ALSA snd-dummy)

Tags: linux, docker, linux-kernel, alsa, pulseaudio

I am using a docker image which does not have the ALSA's snd-dummy module available. I need to emulate a sound card. I do not need (or want) to listen to audio.

Based on the many searches I have done I am rather certain that I want to use ALSA's snd-dummy module for emulating a sound card, which is essentially /dev/null.

Looking over the guide for ALSA Matrix:Module-dummy, it states that if "modinfo soundcore" returns that you have this module, then you don't need to recompile your kernel.

In my instance, I do NOT have "soundcore" or "sound" available. I gather that this means I have to recompile the kernel. Recompiling the kernel of a docker image is a new concept to me. Docker is a new concept to me.

#### In sort, I need to install ALSA's snd-dummy module onto a Linux docker image, which does NOT have soundcore/sound compiled into the kernel.

Docker Image:
https://github.com/fcwu/docker-ubuntu-vnc-desktop

ALSA Matrix snd-dummy:
https://www.alsa-project.org/main/index.php/Matrix:Module-dummy

Is this a potential solution for me?:
https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/sound/drivers/dummy.c

#### Edit:

When replacing ~/.asoundrc to the following and running "alsactl restore" I get the following output. Also, my host machine's volume is affected.

```
# .asoundrc

pcm.dummy {
   type hw
   card 0
}

ctl.dummy {
   type hw
   card 0
}
```

> #### $ alsactl restore
>
> alsactl: load_state:1683: Cannot open /var/lib/alsa/asound.state for
>   reading: No such file or directory Found hardware: "HDA-Intel"
>   "Realtek ALC269VB" "HDA:10ec0269,10280446,00100100
>   HDA:80862805,80860101,00100000" "0x1028" "0x0446" Hardware is
>
> #### initialized using a generic method Found hardware: "Dummy" "Dummy
>
> Mixer" "" "" "" Hardware is initialized using a generic method

Comment: ALSA has (had?) been developed as a stand-alone driver for a long to me. I dunno if they provide such a possibility, but it will be one option.

Answer (score 2):

I think the solution would be to mount the sound device into docker, the problem here that you must use `privileged`:

```
docker run  -v /dev/snd:/dev/snd --privileged myImage ...
```

**UPDATE** 
you may also insert kernel module snd-aloop and specify 2 as the index of sound loop device on your host:

```
sudo modprobe snd-aloop index=2
docker run -it --rm -p 6080:80 --device /dev/snd -e ALSADEV=hw:2,0 dorowu/ubuntu-desktop-lxde-vnc
```

Comment: Thank you LinPy. This all baffles me. Perhaps I am going about this all wrong. I am able to use --device /dev/snd to pass my host machines soundcard into the container/docker. If I watch youtube on my host machine, and another instance on my docker container, the docker container cannot access the sound card.   So if the sound card is allowed/privileged into the docker image, how would I set snd-dummy? The snd-dummy module doesn't exist in the docker images kernel. Also the "apt source linux-image-$(uname -r)" can't find the image.

Comment: Alright, thank you for having taken the time LinPy.